# Unable to scope access token

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oauth-2.0, scope, nestjs

I'm developing a  [unity asset store](https://assetstore.unity.com/) with a React frontend and NestJS Backend.
The Authorisation is implemented using Auth0. The frontend being a Single Page Application (SPA) while the Backend, as mentioned earlier, utilises JwtUserGuard to check tokens.

I am basically trying to create a guard that validates user IDs in order to provide access to the users. The following is the RolesGuard:

```
@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private readonly httpService: HttpService,
        private readonly reflector: Reflector,
        private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    ) {
    }

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const token = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');
        const sub = this.jwtService.decode(token).sub;
        
        const userRole = (await this.httpService.axiosRef.get(
            `https://_____________________/api/v2/users/${sub}/roles`,
            {
                headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}
            }
        ));
        
        const role = this.reflector.get<string>(ROLES_KEY, context.getHandler())[0];
        
        return role === userRole.data
    }
}
```

Everything works well with test access token from Auth0 Management API but when I try to get an access token from the frontend
( Refer to the **index.js** below):

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Auth0Provider
        domain="{myDomain}"
        clientId="{myClientId}"
        authorizationParams={{
            redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
            audience: "https://{myDomain}/api/v2/",
            scope: "read:current_user update:current_user_metadata"
        }}
    >
        <App/>
    </Auth0Provider>
);
```

**Profile.js**

```
...
const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently({
                    authorizationParams: {
                        audience: `https://${domain}/api/v2/`,
                        scope: "read:current_user",
                    },
                });
...
```

And try to pass it to my endpoint, I get the following error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Insufficient scope, expected any of: read:users,read:roles,read:role_members",
    "errorCode": "insufficient_scope"
}
```

A look at the access token scope revealed the following:

```
"scope": "openid read:current_user update:current_user_metadata"
```

*It turns out, `read:users,read:roles,read:role_members` must be  added to the `authorizationParams`'s scope of the  `Auth0Provider`.
This is the primary problem. I tried to add scope here in the following manner:*

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Auth0Provider
        domain="{myDomain}"
        clientId="{myClientId}"
        authorizationParams={{
            redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
            audience: "https://{myDomain}/api/v2/",
            scope: "read:current_user update:current_user_metadata read:users read:roles read:role_members"
        }}
    >
        <App/>
    </Auth0Provider>
);
```

But my access token scope remains the same. I don't really understand how scope works. I went through the auth0 docs to find useful info about this issue, but it didn’t turn out to be of much help.

Comment: Did you add the scope to `getAccessTokenSilently` call, maybe it causes the error and not the provider?